# Input Encoding bugged on Windows 7 WinEdt?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, font-encodings, input-encodings, winedt

When my girlfriend processes her code in WinEdt on Windows 7, she gets awkward looking "special" letters. (Precisly, these are Serbian letters -- from our home country.) 
She used:

```
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbian]{babel}  % This isn't relevant here, but I put it for perspective
```

She also put document properties to `utf8`, so when she types, all the letters should be encoded in utf8, right? But when she processes her file with `pdflatex`, she gets [this pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yr3l62wdi0vcns/file_m.pdf).
Notice how normal alphabet letters are fine, but the serbian letters (2nd line, word određeno) are different from the others.

But, when I process the same `.tex` file on my Mac (with TexShop), I get a [normal looking pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jamqk1lxvlh2gy3/file_v.pdf).
You can see that it looks regular, although I used the exact same code as her.

Why does this happen? She uses `utf8` encoding on her WinEdt, and also in the document. Shouldn't it work fine?

**EDIT:** The solution is to include CM-Super font family into MikTex, and it works perfectly. So I guess whenever people have problems regarding European languages and special character formatting, you should check for CM-Super fonts :)

Comment: A wild guess: maybe you are not using the same and/or up to date TeX distro?

Comment: I guess the problem is always the same: she hasn't the CM-Super fonts on her machine. Try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` or install the CM-Super package with the MiKTeX wizard.

Comment: @Kevin C Well she installed the newest MikTex three days ago, I doubt that's the problem. If anything, I should be the one with the outdated TeX compiler, and yet it works fine for me :)

Comment: @egreg Wow, it works perfectly! I really don't understand why those CM-Super packages are needed here if we're using babel, or why it doesn't include the package automatically. Regardless, thank you very much, and it's not the first time you helped me!
P.S. My girlfriend Mila is very grateful, too! :)

Comment: Babel doesn't include the fonts to display the characters. Its job is to do things like localisation and hyphenation. For example, it makes sure that the table of contents is called 'Cynnwys' and that 'prifysgol' is properly hyphenated if necessary to get good line breaks. But it doesn't include any fonts. So to create the PDF, pdftex needs to have the right glyphs (pictures of the characters). CM-Super covers Serbian, I guess, whereas the standard CM don't. As to why MikTeX doesn't include it, I've no idea. (TeX Live does which is why it works on your Mac.)

Comment: MiKTeX does include cm-super, but not in the basic installation; one then has to install them with the package manager if needed.